# Unable to connect to docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-swarm

I setup two swarm manager nodes(mgr1, mgr2).  But when I try to connect to the container it throws an error message .

```
[root@ip-10-3-2-24 ec2-user]# docker run --restart=unless-stopped -h mgr1 --name mgr1 -d -p 3375:2375 swarm manage --replication --advertise 10.3.2.24:3375 consul://10.3.2.24:8500/                

[root@ip-10-3-2-24 ec2-user]# docker exec -it mgr1 /bin/bash
```

> rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory"

It's happening in both the servers(mgr1, mgr2). I'm also running consul container on each node and able to connect to the consul containers.

Comment: A bit off-topic but you can't use Docker 1.12.3 ? Because with this version you can use the Swarm mode which is easier to setup

Answer (score 4):

`/bin/bash` might not be available there in the container. You may use `sh` as shown below

`docker exec -it mgr1 sh` or
`docker exec -it mgr1 /bin/sh` or
`docker exec -it mgr1 bash` or
`docker attach mgr1`

**UPDATE: Based on the comments**
`busybox` is very light weight linux based image and some of the above works perfectly fine:

```
bash $ sudo docker exec -it test1 bash
rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"bash\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
bash $ sudo docker exec -it test1 sh
/ # exit
bash $ sudo docker exec -it test1 /bin/sh
/ # exit
bash $ sudo docker attach test1
/ # exit
bash $
```

Comment: You mean none of the above two commands help? What is the base image in your case? And what is the output of command `docker ps`?

Comment: Base Image is Amazon Linux.   Here is the detailed info : https://s3.amazonaws.com/va-awsconfig/343434343.PNG

Comment: How about other part of earlier request / comment?

Comment: #docker exec -it mgr1 sh
rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: thanks. updated answer, please check the 3rd command. by the way, are you using `ambakshi/amazon-linux` image?

Comment: No, I've used Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09.0 (HVM), installed docker, consul and swarm manager. yes, I tried with 3rd command also, error. docker exec -it mgr1 bash
rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: @code4geeks, that is quite strange. and thanks for trying out. May last one, check this please `docker attach mgr1`

Comment: Tried, with attach also but it hangs and at last I've to hit ctrl + c, which kill the container :(

Comment: If nothing custom in the image,  you want to create another container and see ? use different base image for testing?

Comment: Yes, it looks like something wrong with generic Amazon image. I tried in another instance also and noticed the same issue.                                #docker exec -it 80102440981a echo $SHELL
rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"echo\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: what does it return when you hit `docker exec mgr1 which sh`?

Comment: #docker exec mgr1 which sh   
rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"which\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: @code4geeks, Thank you so much for your efforts. `busybox` is very light weight image and you can see those commands in action (updated answer).